# Method declaration on employee1 invalid need return type

Tags: java

I am getting an error on public static Employee1 saying it needs a return type required and that the method declaration is invalid. Ive tried changing it around but I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I am sorry I am kind of new to java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aleko_Employee1 extends Object
{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private char middleInitial;
private boolean fulltime;
private char gender;
private int employeeNum;
private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public class aleko_Employee1
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    aleko_Employee1 employee1 = new aleko_Employee1("Jeff", "Doe", 'M', 12345);
    aleko_Employee1 employee2 = new aleko_Employee1("Jeffery", "Doe", 'M', 12345);
    aleko_Employee1 employee3 = new aleko_Employee1("Amanda", "Smith", 'M', 98765);
}
public static Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{

    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    gender = g;
    employeNum = en;
}

public void setfirstName(String fn)
{
    firstName = fn;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String ln)
{
    lastName=ln;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setGender(char g)
{
    gender =g;
}

public char getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

public void setEmployeeNumber(int en)
{

    if ( en > 99999 || en < 10000)
    {
        employeeNum = en;
    }
    else
    {
        employeeNum = 0;
    }
}
public int getEmployeeNumber();
{
    return employeeNum;
}

public boolean equals( Object e2)
{
    if (this.employeeNum == ((Employee1)e2).employeeNum)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public String toString()
{
    return lastName + ","+ "\n" + "ID:" + employeeNum + "\n";
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
public static Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{
...
}
```

to (you always need to specify a return type in methods, if it does not return anything it is `void`)

```
public static void Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{
...
}
```

or if it is supposed to be a constructor (You do not specify a return type in constructors)

```
public aleko_Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{
...
}
```

Comment: sorry about that, I had just copy pasted.

Comment: Thank you very much it is the public aleko_Employee1

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried to define a constructor but ended up defining a method here:

```
public static Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{

    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    gender = g;
    employeNum = en;
}
```

Constructors need to have the same name as of Class and they don't have any return types. So change it to:

```
public aleko_Employee1(String fn, String ln, char g,  int en)
{

    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    gender = g;
    employeNum = en;
}
```

Constructor is called when you create an object using `new` operator. So now when you create your objects as mentioned here:

```
aleko_Employee1 employee1 = new aleko_Employee1("Jeff", "Doe", 'M', 12345);
aleko_Employee1 employee2 = new aleko_Employee1("Jeffery", "Doe", 'M', 12345);
aleko_Employee1 employee3 = new aleko_Employee1("Amanda", "Smith", 'M', 98765);
```

JVM will call the matching constructor as mentioned above.